# apsw.SQLError: SQLError: no such vfs: zipvfs when trying to read encrypted SQLite files on Windows using python & apsw

Tags: python, sqlite, zlib, apsw

I have a code that works under linux and I am trying to port it to windows. It uses apsw to work with encrypted SQLite files.

```
flags = apsw.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | apsw.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | apsw.SQLITE_OPEN_URI

connection_string = (
  "file:{filepath}?zv=zlib&level=9&vfs=zipvfs&password256={password}".format(
    filepath=filepath, password=password
  )
)

connection = apsw.Connection(connection_string, flags=flags)
```

when I try to run it under windows, it throws this error:

```
apsw.SQLError: SQLError: no such vfs: zipvfs
```

I have downloaded `zlibwapi.dll` and put it under System32, I have also tried building `apsw` from source

```
python setup.py fetch --all build --enable-all-extensions install
```

but I am still getting the error. (tried in python 3.10 and 3.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclosure: I am the APSW author)

ZipVFS is a [separately licensed](https://www.sqlite.org/zipvfs/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki) piece of software.  That is why APSW can't download and include it when you requested everything to be fetched and all extensions enabled.  As far as I can tell `zlibwapi.dll` is the compression routines only, and doesn't include the zipvfs code.

You will need to do under Windows what you did under Linux to get zipvfs code included.  At a minimum what should work is to create a `sqlite3` directory where you have the APSW source, and in that `sqlite3` directory place `sqlite3-zipvfs.c` named `sqlite3.c`.  Then run your `setup.py` line again, but exclude the fetch bit.  In the first few lines of output you will see something like this differing by the directory you are in.

```
SQLite: Using amalgamation C:\projects\apsw\sqlite3\sqlite3.c
```